# revtex split footnotes

Tags: footnotes, revtex

Using revtex4-1, long footnotes get cut off at the end of pages. This only happens with the `nofootinbib` option. I am using `hyperref` which throws an error when I try to put `\usepackage{bigfoot}` in the preamble. How can I either

a) increase the size of the footnote and keep it all on one page, or

b) break the footnote before the text runs off the edge of the page?

Below is a minimal example where the footnote gets cut off after "...risus porta vehicula".

```
\documentclass[nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\footnote{\lipsum}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I’ve not made extensive investigations, but as far as I can presently understand, this looks like a bug in the `revtex4-1` class.  It turns out that the value of `\count\footins` is 500, which would be appropriate if footnotes were typeset in two columns, as it is not the case in your example.  Resetting the correct value `\count\footins = 1000` *after* `\begin{document}` solves the issue:

```
\documentclass[nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
% \usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \tracingpages = 1

\begin{document}

\count\footins = 1000

\lipsum

Footnoted text.\footnote{\lipsum}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Recall that the value of the `\count` register associated to an insertion is used to extimate by how much that insertion affects the page goal; more precisely, an insertion having height-plus-depth equal to *x* is assumed to decrease the page goal by (roughly) *xf*/1000, where *f* is the value of the `\count` register in question.  So, in your example, TeX erroneously assumed that the footnote was half as high as it actually was, thus understimating by a factor of two the vertical space that needed to be reserved for it.