# Long footnotes exceeding page bounds (revtex4-1)

Tags: footnotes, margins, revtex

I've got some long footnotes that are exceeding the text bounding box and overflowing into the footer. This becomes a problem when they overlap with the page numbers.

Here's an MWE of what I'm getting:

```
\documentclass[nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[pass, showframe]{geometry}

\parskip = 1mm

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

Here we are about to have a footnote\footnote{\blindtext[2]}. \blindtext\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Note that I've turned on `showframe` in the geometry package to see what's going on. Here's the result:

[image: Screenshot of MWE]

Note that the footnote is completely overflowing into the footer and beyond.

I'm not sure what's causing this behavior. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Works fine with `article` class, so something to do with `revtex4-1`.

Comment: Indeed. Unfortunately, I need `revtex4-1` for other purposes and can't switch to `article`.

Comment: Since revtex is made with a very specific purpose, perhaps this is intentional, trying to keep people from writing excessively long footnotes.

Comment: @Jolyon: Yep. Wasn't trying to suggest you switch. My comment was just to narrow down the problem to the class.

Comment: Some more playing: If you add `twocolumn` to the document class options, it behaves properly. So it's an issue with footnotes in onecolumn mode in revtex4-1... sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague passed along this solution: add `\count\footins = 1000` immediately after `\begin{document}`. I don't know what it does or how it does it, but apparently it works the required magic. Explanations welcome.

Comment: And here's an explanation (that I still don't understand): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373464/revtex-split-footnotes

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.