# Footnote overwriting bottom centered page number

Tags: footnotes, etoolbox, revtex

I am using the etoolbox package to set the footnote spacing to single spaced inside my double spaced document.  However, if I have a lot of footnotes on a page, they overwrite the page number.  How can I get my footnotes to respect the normal bottom margin as on pages without footnotes?

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\footnotesep=10pt
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
{\setspace@singlespace}{0.8}
{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Exciting Title about Interesting Subject}
\author{Fantastic Author}
\affiliation{Magnificent Affiliation}
\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newpage
\raggedbottom
\pagenumbering{arabic}  
\setcounter{page}{1}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.    This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number.  This footnote tends to overlap the page number}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It does not happen with `twocolumn`,  (joining four foonotes together, one after the other).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A colleague passed along this solution: add \count\footins = 1000 immediately after \begin{document}. I don't know what it does or how it does it, but apparently it works the required magic.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453708/218690

Answer (score 1):

Try this in preamble

```
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
    \begingroup%
    \linespread{1}%    % <- linespread for footnote: 1, 1.1, 1.2 etc
    \oldfootnote{#1}%
    \endgroup%
}
```

And if you want the footnote not to go to the other page you can set:

`\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000`